# PHP Recursively collect SimpleXMLElement data and flatten array of arrays

Tags: php, xml, recursion, simplexml

Im trying to build an array structure based off of xmldata. I believe the issue has to do with how Im handling `$finalData`. I eventually want a flattened array containing three arrays of records, but I imagine I need to first parse the XML data correctly and then work on flattening the array of data. I wanted to fix the code to parse the XML data, so my initial question is how do I fix this code to parse the XML data, but then I was going to work on how to flatten the final data array(i need the individual `record` structures that contain the pertinent information i eventually need. I guess you can say Im trying to handle a user import of data and ultimately retrieve just the individual components that contain the data.

```
public function processXml($xmldata,$finalData=array())
{
    $finalData = array();
    if($xmldata instanceof SimpleXMLElement){
        foreach($xmldata as $idata){
            $this->processXml($idata,$finalData);
        }
    } else {
        array_push($finalData,$xmldata);
    }
    return $finalData;  
}
```

Here's the XML Data (note that I do not know what the user will be importing in his XML data, this is just test data that i created):

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <configdata>
        <records>
             <somekey>
                <record>
                    <firstname>Jonathan</firstname>
                    <lastname>Kushner</lastname>
                </record>
                <record>
                    <firstname>Dustin</firstname>
                    <lastname>Kushner</lastname>
                </record>
                <record>
                    <firstname>Cameron</firstname>
                    <lastname>Kushner</lastname>
                </record>
            </somekey>
        </records>
    </configdata>`
```

NOTE: The answers provided use xpath and domdocument. Im trying to learn recursion and flattening so although it is a better approach, I still wish to figure out how to implement this using just recursion and flattening.

Comment: Please show the input XML and resulting array you would like (note: converting an XML document to an array usually results in a loss of the semantics of the data). Also, possible quick fix, you will want to either pass `$finalData` by reference or merge the result of the recursive call with it, try `public function processXml($xmldata, &$finalData = null) { if (!isset($finalData)) { $finalData = array(); } /* rest of the method code */ }`

Comment: fixed the question. also, i tried your solution and it did not work.

Comment: So what would you like out of this XML? Just an array of 3 names as strings?

Comment: Id like to eventually have three arrays containing firstname and last name, but i thought id have to parse the XML data and then work on flattening the array containing three inner arrays of data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than the recursive loop carpet-bomb approach, it is far better to use [XPath](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php) to extract only the data you want in a precise way.

Here's how you can acheive what you want:

```
// Create the document object
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlData);

$result = array();

// Get the <record> nodes and loop them
foreach ($xml->xpath('//record') as $record) {
    // to get the text data from a node in SimpleXML, just cast it to a string
    $result[] = array(
        'firstname' => (string) $record->firstname,
        'lastname' => (string) $record->lastname,
    );
}

print_r($result);
```

[See it working](http://codepad.org/KKndkXEo)

To take all child elements from the `$record` without knowing it's name, you can use:

```
$result[] = array_map(
    'strval', 
     iterator_to_array($record->children())
);
```

Take note that same-names elements (which is possible in XML) will not work in an array. Here only the last element with the same name will survive.

*Edit*

This can also still be done with XPath but you will need to use DOM instead of SimpleXML (this shouldn't be a problem, it's available everywhere). You can do something like this:

```
// Create the document object
$doc = new DOMDocument;

// This is required in order to ignore the pretty-print whitspace
$doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;

// load the data into the object
$doc->loadXML($xmlData);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);

$result = array();

// Get the text nodes and loop them
foreach ($xpath->query('//text()') as $record) {
    $result[] = $record->data;
}

print_r($result);
```

[See it working](http://codepad.org/RdyDBaKt)

Comment: I didnt make it clear that I dont know what the keys are, so I cannot do an xpath of a key. Ill update the question.

Comment: @jkushner: That works basically the same, you just use `$record->children()` to get all (unknown named) child-elements. Put those into the array and you should be fine. You can find an edit in the answer.

Comment: Im trying to learn recursion, even if its noit the best approach. Can you help with my recursive and flattening siolution?

Comment: @jkushner While you are to be commended for wanting to learn something new, trying to learn recursion by looping an XML document is not really a great way to do it, especially doing what you are doing here - you will never get to a point where the thing you are looping is not a `SimpleXMLElement` because that's not how SimpleXML works. [Here](http://faculty.ycp.edu/~dhovemey/spring2008/cs201/info/recursionPractice.html) are some practice recursion problems (ignore 2 and 4, tail recursion is not possible in PHP). Start small and work upwards ;-)

Comment: I see. Thanks than for introducing me to the best approaches for PHP XML.

Comment: Using the DOMDOcument method returns a onedimensional array containing all the data. I would need three arrays, each containing the data for that record. How do I fix the DOMDocument method?

Comment: @jkushner The best way to do this would probably be with two xpath queries: first get the nodes where the direct children have a direct child of a text node, then loop those and get the data you want, hang on I'll run up and example

Comment: @jkushner http://codepad.org/isAAHO9z - also another recursion task you could do: implement the `$recusive` argument of `mkdir()` youself. So write a function that, given a directory path, will create all components of that path that don't exist one level at a time.

Comment: Thanks. Thats precisely what I need. My only question is how do I handle incorrect XML Data(the data is not in a format where I can extract the records in the same fashion)

Comment: Also, I will definitely try the `mkdir` recursive task you provided.Thanks for the information.

Comment: @jkushner can you show some example incorrect data? If you mean the XML is syntactically invalid, using the `loadHTML()` method of `DOMDocument` instead of `loadXML()`  is a lot more forgiving of things like this, and for what you are doing the XPath would still work if you did this.

Comment: Heres incorrect data: http://pastebin.com/hvdgfDQQ. Lastly, Im having difficulty findinig information online that can explain your xpath queries. I tried looking at the php xpath query API, but its not helpful. If Im going to use this solution, Id like to understand how the queries work. Can you explain the xpath queries on your solution?

Comment: @jkushner The XPath documentation is particularly bad for accessibility actually, depressingly I think w3schools has one of the better simple/legible sets of docs for it, although it does miss a lot of information out. The official standard/spec for XPath 1.0 (which is what PHP uses) is [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/). The incorrect structure can be handled by adding another condition to verify that the matched nodes don't contain any nodes that *don't* match the expression: http://codepad.org/V0jArURn

Comment: Thanks for all the great information. Im super psyched about learning PHP XML.

Comment: @jkushner I asked hakre (who edited in the stuff about above about `iterator_to_array()`) for a better docs link (I tend to just read the spec these days) and he provided http://schlitt.info/opensource/blog/0704_xpath.html - if you want to discuss this any further come and join us in [PHP chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11/php), this comment thread has got kinda too long ;-)